# get email using openid and python

Tags: python, email, authentication, openid

I'm trying to get an e-mail address from an OpenId request using the following form below and web.py.  I get an OpenId hash back, but I don't see anything related to an e-mail in my apache environment--just a openid_identity_hash.

This is my html form using web.py.

```
<input type="text" name="openid" value="" style="background: url(http://openid.net/login-bg.gif) no-repeat; padding-left: 18px; background-position: 0 50%%;" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="${returnUrl}" />
<input type="hidden" name="openid.ns.ext1" value="http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0" />
<input type="hidden" name="openid.ext1.mode" value="fetch_request" />
<input type="hidden" name="openid.ext1.type.email" value="http://axschema.org/contact/email" />
<input type="hidden" name="openid.ext1.required" value="email" />
```

Looking at the docs linked off of Google's dev site to OpenID, I've found these attributes to include, which I feel like I'm doing.

```
openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
openid.ax.mode=fetch_request
openid.ax.type.fname=http://example.com/schema/fullname
openid.ax.type.gender=http://example.com/schema/gender
openid.ax.type.fav_dog=http://example.com/schema/favourite_dog
openid.ax.type.fav_movie=http://example.com/schema/favourite_movie
openid.ax.count.fav_movie=3
openid.ax.required=fname,gender
openid.ax.if_available=fav_dog,fav_movie
openid.ax.update_url=http://idconsumer.com/update?transaction_id=a6b5c4
```

But it never actually asks to approve the e-mail request and I don't see it in my environment.  Does web.py just not support it?  Can I use something else like authkit to query the e-mail afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

@voodo , Try setting these values.

```
openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&
openid.ns.alias3=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&
openid.alias3.if_available=alias1,alias2,alias3&
openid.alias3.required=alias4&
openid.alias3.mode=fetch_request&
openid.alias3.type.alias1=http://schema.openid.net/namePerson&
openid.alias3.count.alias1=1&
openid.alias3.type.alias2=http://schema.openid.net/contact/email&
openid.alias3.count.alias2=1&
openid.alias3.type.alias3=http://axschema.org/namePerson&
openid.alias3.count.alias3=1&
openid.alias3.type.alias4=http://axschema.org/contact/email&
openid.alias3.count.alias4=1
```

I am not sure why this works and pure AX schema does not, even though google's XRDS specifies supporting AX schema

Comment: I've changed my form (http://pastebin.com/nhh6d8Cq), but I still don't see any thing related to an e-mail back from apache's environment.

Comment: @voodo, Looking at the form shared at pastebin, there are number of essential parameters which you are not passing like openid.claimed_id, openid.identity,openid.mode,openid.realm and return_to should be named openid.return_to

Comment: Updated your form at http://pastebin.com/105AjtEW. You just need to handle the response from google and verify the response to allow your users to the dashboard of your app

Comment: I added those attributes to the form, but I'm still not sure what should be visible after login.  All I see is from web.py's status function which returns a OpenID hash.  Is something hidden inside python-openid containing the e-mail that web.py doesn't directly provide?